# Column headings keep appearing throughout Oracle output

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

After ever 10 lines, my column headers reappear in my Oracle output.  Is there something about my code or some kind of environment variable I can set to stop this?  I only need the column headers to appear once at the top of my results.

```
BREAK ON Customer
COLUMN Customer -
       FORMAT A15 -
       HEADING 'Customer Name'
COLUMN "Charter Date" -
       HEADING 'Charter|Date'
COLUMN Pilot -
       FORMAT A20 -
       HEADING 'Pilot'
SELECT DECODE (cu.cus_initial,null, cu.cus_fname||' '||cu.cus_lname,
       cu.cus_fname||' '||cu.cus_initial||'. '||cu.cus_lname)
       AS Customer,
       ch.char_date "Charter Date",
       TRIM( e.emp_fname) ||' '|| TRIM(e.emp_lname) AS "Pilot"
FROM hartmar.customer cu,
     hartmar.charter ch,
     hartmar.crew cr,
     hartmar.pilot p,
     hartmar.employee e
WHERE cu.cus_code = ch.cus_code
      AND ch.char_trip = cr.char_trip
      AND cr.emp_num = p.emp_num
      AND p.emp_num = e.emp_num
      AND cr.crew_type = 'Pilot'
ORDER BY cu.cus_lname, cu.cus_fname, cu.cus_initial, ch.char_date
;

CLEAR BREAKS
CLEAR COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 30):

Assuming you're running this in SQL*Plus, you need to set your pagesize.

```
SET PAGESIZE 50000
```

will cause the columns headings to appear only once for every 50,000 rows returned.  I believe 50,000 is the maximum PAGESIZE setting.

If you want to eliminate headers entirely, you can set the `PAGESIZE` to 0 but that will suppress even the first set of headers

```
SQL> set pagesize 0;
SQL> select ename, empno from emp;
PAV              7623
smith            7369
ALLEN            7499
WARD             7521
JONES            7566
MARTIN           7654
BLAKE            7698
CLARK            7782
SCOTT            7788
KING             7839
TURNER           7844
ADAMS            7876
SM0              7900
FORD             7902
MILLER           7934
BAR              1234

16 rows selected.
```

Comment: SET PAGESIZE 50000 worked like a charm.  My problem was that I was entering that into the login.sql file as SET PAGESIZE = xxxxx when the '=' symbol wasn't necessary.  Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Use a 'hidden' feature that will suppress all EXCEPT the first row of headings!

```
set pagesize 0 embedded on
```

Thanks to "Bruno Ruess" via https://community.oracle.com/thread/2389479?start=0&tstart=0 for the above.

If you then also add

```
SET UNDERLINE off
```

Then you can supress the "underlining" of the header row, and get to something that looks a lot more like a CSV.

Comment: Genius! EMBEDDED ON

Answer (score 2):

You can also:

```
SET PAGESIZE 0
```

To stop all column headers after the start of your report.

Comment: A PAGESIZE of 0 suppresses all column headers.  It doesn't even display headers at the beginning of the report.

Comment: You may try `set pagesize 0 embedded on`