# Display Student's firstname and course enrolled by him in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

people the question is to write a query to display the student's first name alone with the course name that they have registered. Sort the result based on student's first name and course name.

Here is my attempt to solve the problem,

```
select FirstName,CourseName from student s
inner join registration r on s.StudID=r.StudId
inner join course c on r.CourseID=c.CourseID
order by FirstName asc,CourseName asc;
```

This is the schema for the tables
[image]

The output i get when i run the code is this 
[image: output]

Where am i going wrong? please help people.

Comment: Why do you think something has gone wrong? Your code looks like it works and appears to generate an output. What were you expecting? Apart from that, your schema diagram does not have a `registration` or a `course` table and please don't post images of text (just copy/paste the text and format it neatly).

Comment: Sorry i uploaded the wrong schema.. the output seems to be printing two tables as you can see in the picture i think they should be printed in the same table

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. [ask]

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7617396/1509264

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: you can use 
set pagesize 0
or in short you can throw in newpage also in same line !
set pages 0 newp0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> the output seems to be printing two tables as you can see in the picture i think they should be printed in the same table

No, it isn't. You appear to be using SQL/Plus and its all part of the same output; its just that after a certain number of rows SQL/Plus will re-print the column headers.

The commands for SQL/Plus are given [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm) and you should be able to use:

```
SET PAGESIZE 10000
```

(Or some other large value) and that will set the number of rows that SQL/Plus will output before it repeats the headers. Then you can re-run your query and the repeated headers will not be printed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. still learning everything the more you get to know the better i guess ! thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

I did this and got the required output.

```
select FirstName,CourseName from ((student s
inner join registration r on s.StudID=r.StudId)
inner join course c on r.CourseID=c.CourseID)
order by FirstName asc,CourseName asc;
```

Comment: Query looks good, Please add some explanation to you answer too